# Converting a large matrix into an image

Tags: opencv, matrix

hi so I've got a large 33 x 33 matrix in a text file. I've been working on an opencv project which basically reads the frames and calculates the similarities. So basically, I now have this large text file filled with numbers. How do I visualize this matrix in say a 2D grayscale image?

Comment: what's the format of your txt file ? yml/xml ? then it's plain cv::FileStorage

Answer (score 1):

Is your matrix a `cv::Mat` object?

If so, do:

```
cv::Mat matrix;

//Load the matrix from the file
matrix = ...

//show the matrix
imshow("window name", matrix);

//save the image
imwrite("image.png", matrix);
```

If not, then do:

```
cv::Mat matrix = cv::Mat.create(33, 33, CV_32FC1);
float* floatPtr = matrix.ptr<float>();

for (int i=0;i<33*33;i++)
     //read data from file here
    *floatPtr++ = data[i] //if it's in an array
    //If you have a file stream then do: file>>*floatPtr++;

//show the image
imshow("window name", matrix);

//save the image
imwrite("image.png", matrix);
```